# Are there dual pilot planes to pilot myself?

Tags: flight-training

I understand planes have 2 piloting systems often?

Is there a plane I can demo fly first flight?

I'm interested in saying I have flown and that's it.

Comment: Go to any flight school and ask to take a "discovery flight". You will handle the controls most of the time. BTW, they are called "yokes" or "controls", not "steering wheels". Only one plane had a steering wheel (that I know of, not including the flying cars or esoteric experimentals).

Comment: @RonBeyer  - Doolittle’s Trimotor has steering wheels. The entire cockpit looks like a Ford from that era. It even has roll-down windows (millennials may need to Google that). I wish I could attach a picture. The rear seat legroom is incredible. More than my Beemer. Certainly more than any other 4 seater I have ever flown.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the vast majority of airplanes have dual controls. You can just call up your local flight school and explain what you want. A "Discovery Flight" is typically 30 minutes of flying, just to see if you're interested, but if you want to go for longer than that, just let them know beforehand.

Comment: And most introductory flights will let you take control.